# EF - Changing table name not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Changing my table names doesn't seem to be working with different. So i decided to do a test on a separate project just to clarify what i've tried so far.

1. I already have a database with 4 tables "Restaurants" and "Restaurants2" has the same structure
2. I started a new mvc 4 project "Internet Application" being selected
3. Created 3 class

**Database**

[image]

**Error message**

[image]
**Code**

```
public class MyDB : DbContext
{
    public MyDB()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }
    //(1) protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    //Changing Database table name to Metadata
    //    modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
    //        .ToTable("Restaurants2");
    //}
    //(2) protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>().ToTable("Restaurants2");
    //    // otherwise EF assumes the table is called "Products"
    //}
    //(3) protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    //}
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
//[Table("Restaurants2")]
public class Restaurant
{
    //[Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //[Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //[Column("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    //[Column("Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
public class RestaurantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

1. Firstly if you look at the code while ignoring the comments i started of my project like that initially. And it works as i can see restaurant data is being display.
2. My aim is to display Tables "Restaurants2" using the same entity, so what i did is added attribute etc. [Table("Restaurants2")] to my restaurant class. But this gave me an error.
3. Ive commented out all attributes in my restaurant class and used "(1) OnModelCreating" function, but that gave me the same error
4. Then i try the second "(2) OnModelCreating" function and it still gave me the same error
5. I went back to my initial state where i started off from the beginning and then i change my "Restaurant" class name to "Restaurants2" but it still gave me the same error
6. I then used the third "(3) OnModelCreating" function hoping it doesn't pluralize my table name and still it gave me the same error.

I am really out of luck!!! What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run the `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` commands after you changed your entities models?

Comment: No.. i give that a try

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider It doesn't give me any errors now, but is not displaying any data

Comment: You probably have to copy the data from the old `Restaurant` table to the new `Restaurant2` table.

Comment: I restarted the whole process again but first i enable migrating and then every time i make changes i use Update-database, now it works. Thanks for helping @GeorgPatscheider